# r: using `for` and `if` to run run function on numeric vars only

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a four column dataframe with `date`, `var1_share`, `var2_share`, and `total`. I want to multiply each of the `share` metrics against the `total` only to create new variables containing the raw values for both `var1` & `var2`. See below code (a bit verbose) to construct the dataframe that contains the share variables:

```
df<- data.frame(dt= seq.Date(from = as.Date('2019-01-01'), 
    to= as.Date('2019-01-10'), by= 'day'),
    var1= round(runif(10, 3, 12), digits = 1), 
    var2= round(runif(10, 3, 12), digits = 1))
df$total<- apply(df[2:3], 1, sum)
ratio<- lapply(df[-1], function(x) x/df$total)
ratio<- data.frame(ratio)
df<- cbind.data.frame(df[1],ratio)
colnames(df)<- c('date', 'var1_share', 'var2_share', 'total')
df
```

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
> df
date var1_share var2_share total
1  2019-01-01  0.5862069  0.4137931     1
2  2019-01-02  0.6461538  0.3538462     1
3  2019-01-03  0.3591549  0.6408451     1
4  2019-01-04  0.7581699  0.2418301     1
5  2019-01-05  0.3989071  0.6010929     1
6  2019-01-06  0.5132743  0.4867257     1
7  2019-01-07  0.5230769  0.4769231     1
8  2019-01-08  0.4969325  0.5030675     1
9  2019-01-09  0.5034965  0.4965035     1
10 2019-01-10  0.3254438  0.6745562     1
```

I have nested an `if` statement within a `for` loop, hoping to return a new dataframe called `share`. I want it to skip `date` when using the share variables for I've incorporated `is.numeric` so that it ignores `date`,  however, when I run it, it only returns the date and not the desired result of date, the share of each variable (as separate columns), and the total column. See below code:

```
for (i in df){
  share<- if(is.numeric(i)){
     i * df$total
    } else i
  share<- data.frame(share)
  return(share)
}
share

> share
share
1  2019-01-01
2  2019-01-02
3  2019-01-03
...
```

How do I adjust this function so that `share` returns a dataframe containing date, variable 1 and 2 raw variables, and total?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what your initial data looks like given that your expected output is what I get when I run your code (besides the missing seed for reproducibility).

Answer (score 2):

One could note that multiplying a vector (`*`) with a data.frame, will cast the multiplication **column wise** over the data frame (multiply the vector on column 1, 2, 3 etc.). As such you can do this without any 'apply' by simply using `*` of the total column and the columns you want to multiply.

Or you could make a simple function to achieve the result. Below is such an example.

```
Multi_share <- function(x, total_col = "total"){
  if(is.character(total_col))
    return(x[,sapply(x, is.numeric)[names(x) != total_col]] * x[, total_col])
  if(is.numeric(total_col) && NROW(total_col) == NROW(x))
    return(x[,sapply(x, is.numeric)] * total_col)
  stop("Total unrecognized. Must either be a 1 dimensional vector, a column matrix or a character specifying the total column in R.")
}
cbind(df, Multi_share(df))
```

One could change the names of the columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
share <-df[, sapply(df,is.numeric)]
share <-mapply(function(x) x*share$total, share[,names(share)!="total"])
```

The first line will give you back only numeric columns (so date is filtered). 
The second one will multiply each column (except total) and total.

Comment: Yes, becuase total is always 1. If you change total, so if you " I want to multiply each of the share metrics against the total" as the question states, the result will be the same. My guess is that the real dataset will have total!=1 at some point